# chrome not including 3rd-party cookies in requests

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

The IT department at the company I work for has recently upgraded me to Chrome 91.0.4472.124, and now I am having a problem with an application I'm responsible for.

3rd-party cookies are not being included in cross-domain requests, despite having correct SameSite settings - here is the entire cookie:

```
JSESSIONID=F4C3A14243123754355B3A6645AFFECD; Max-Age=43200; Expires=Sun, 04-Jul-2021 05:54:55 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
```

I've captured the following NetLog trace (actual urls redacted) using chrome's NetLog tool and can see a 'DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES' flag being set for my cross-site requests:

```
=15002 [st= 0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=28]
                 --> priority = "MEDIUM"
                 --> traffic_annotation = 101845102
                 --> url = "https://<siteA><url>"
t=15002 [st= 0]    NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_URL_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=15002 [st= 0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=27]
                   --> initiator = "https://<siteB>"
                   --> load_flags = 16448 (DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES | SUPPORT_ASYNC_REVALIDATION)
                   --> method = "GET"
                   --> network_isolation_key = "https://<domain> https://<domain>"
                   --> privacy_mode = "enabled"
                   --> request_type = "other"
                   --> site_for_cookies = "SiteForCookies: {site=https://<domain>; schemefully_same=true}"
                   --> url = "https://<siteA><url>"
```

Why is DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES being set? Is that why cookies are not being included in requests?

Comment: I have that flag set, too. But I see the cookie being sent from the server (Chrome, F12, network tab, click the request, then cookies tab (only available with cookie present)). Only the client (Chrome) is not saving it (it doesn't appear in (F12, Application tab, Cookies). Have that problem for a week now.